# Move files from Android to Windows PC leaves files on phone

Tags: windows, android

What's the basic reason why when you "cut" a file or files from an Android device it just copies it and leaves the file still on the phone itself?

This happens on my Android version 11 phone. Is there a configuration needed to make sure that when files are "cut" from phone to PC with will not stay on the phone?

Comment: Accessing an Android device via Windows Explorer use MTP protocol. A lot of Android devices have bugs in MTP protocol especially when moving files so that moving a file can end up in just deleting the file, Therefore In my opinion it is recommended to never use move operations in combination with Android phones connected via MTP.

Comment: Note for close-voters "Android devices are off-topic for Super User … ***unless they specifically involve interaction with a computer***"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you cannot file-cut/paste to a different partition or device.
Cut just doesn't work that way, it's designed to simply re-allocate the directory information, the data itself never moves.

Across devices or partitions you would first have to write the new data then delete the old, as two separate steps. This is a *Move* rather than a cut/paste.
On Windows you can initiate this by right-click/drag the data you wish to move & selecting 'Move here' from the contextual menu when it appears

[image] [image]

I can't test this will work when dragging from an Android device.

Comment: Apparently, the issue happens when you don't overwrite the file on the target (if there are); maybe the delete command does not fire back to the phone/device. In the same way, if the move operation was interrupted all the files in the queue are not moved to the phone/device bin. Maybe something with how Android implemented its Network File API. I haven't dig enough to know, but, if all goes well the files on the phones gets deleted.